# Alert user before session expires, option to renew session

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am setting session time in web config. I also have a javascript for detecting session timeout and letting the user know.

I would like to be able to alert the user 30 sec or a min or more before session timeout with a popup and to give them the opportunity to extend it or cancel and just let it timeout. Can this be done? I have tried to use various methods on the internet but none seem to work. They all require that I download something and I don't want to have to do that.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sessionTimeout = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";

    function DisplaySessionTimeout() {
        sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout - 1;

        if (sessionTimeout >= 0)
            window.setTimeout("DisplaySessionTimeout()", 60000);
        else
            alert("Your current Session is over due to inactivity.");
    }
</script>
```

I am also checking for timeout in code behind and rediecting but thinking about just doing it in javascript.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckSession();
}


private void CheckSession()
{
    if (Session["ASP.NET_SessionId"] == null)
    {
       // Session.RemoveAll();
       Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to essentialy have a timer at the same time limit as session; there is no way for the client to know exactly the time the session is at before expiring.  That' what I've done in an application.

We do a JQuery `$.get("keepalive.aspx")` to make a request to an ASP.NET page, which accesses session and refreshes it, keeping the current session alive.  You'd also then reset your client-side timer.  This has worked well for us.

See [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15793.keep-session-alive-in-asp-net-application.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Im not sure how to do this. I am not sure how to do this either : We do a JQuery $.get("keepalive.aspx") what goes in the keepalive page? Does .get just call it?

Comment: `$.get` makes an AJAX request.  It request an ASP.NET page, which is important because the ASP.NET page is a handler that has session available to it.  You just do something with session and that keeps the session alive for another 20 minutes (or whatever session is supposed to be).  So essentially create a keep alive page that does something with session in code behind.  It's only purpose is to be called by JQuery.

Comment: so, in the keep alive page in the load event do something like this: session.timeout = 20;  ??

Comment: I wish you could give me an example on the $.get

Comment: I did with `$.get("keepalive.aspx");`.  That's all you need.

Comment: Hi Brian, where did you implement the timer? Did you implement this on the master page?

Comment: yes, you can do it in the master page.  Note giving them a warning 1 minute before may be a little too close; you may want to do 3 or 5 minutes before.

Comment: Also, your answer does not explain how the session is accessed and refreshed. Is this performed automatically by ASP.NET or must this be performed manually programmatically?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher Anytime a request is made to an ASP.NET page, the ASP.NET framework handles the extension of the session.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://pure-essence.net/2010/02/14/jquery-session-timeout-countdown/) is a good example of how to give a "Session Timeout" warning with Jquery

[Here](http://regretless.com/stuff/jQuery/jQuerySessionTimeoutCountdownWithDialog.html) is a demo of it in action

Comment: This "Async postbacks will not extend session unless you are using cookieless sessions" does not sound true - to my knowledge any request with the cookie will extend session timeout. You may mean something else - would be nice to add links/comment.

Comment: im not sure how to do this: //to extend session use a method such as $.get("keepalive.aspx")

Comment: @Alexie, your right, I meant something else that does not apply here. I modified my answer.

Comment: @icelated, I provided another answer, please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thats exactly what i want. Does this code go into the head section like javascript does? Do i need to download anything?

Comment: I pasted that code into the javas script section but it does anything. Do i need to call it from pageload or something? if so what function?

Comment: @icelated, make sure you reference all the external .js files in the example:   jquery-1.4.1.min.js, jquery-ui-1.8rc1.custom.min.js, jquery.idletimer.js. View source on the demo and look at between the HEAD tags and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Where is the source between the head tags? I mean i dont see the HEAD tags i jst see source code..I dont know how to include all what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You also can check a Microsoft example and it seems exact your issue, please try [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AspNetAlertSessionExpire-c230a148)